# how to create regex from list of strings in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following code where I create a regex from a list of strings,this perfectly suffices my need.I was wondering if there a one liner way of doing this?

```
using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] idlist1 = new string[] { };
            string[] idlist2 = new string[] { };
            string[] idlist3 = new string[] { };
            string id1 = "ABC1234.PIL.5.0-00028-P-1";
            string id2 = "DEF5678.PIL.5.0-00028-E-1";
            string id3 = "GHI9101.PIL.4.0-00135-B-1";

            idlist1 = id1.Split('-');
            idlist2 = id2.Split('-');
            idlist3 = id3.Split('-');
            //create a regex of type ABC1234.PIL.5.0*P*
            //create a regex of type DEF5678.PIL.5.0*E*
            //create a regex of type GHI9101.PIL.4.0.B*
            string regex1 = idlist1[0] + "*" + idlist1[2] + "*" ;
            string regex2 = idlist2[0] + "*" + idlist2[2] + "*";
            string regex3 = idlist3[0] + "*" + idlist3[2] + "*";
            Console.WriteLine(regex1);
            Console.WriteLine(regex2);
            Console.WriteLine(regex3);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

Comment: smells like an XY problem. Why do you want all those regexes in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one liner? seems like an unnecessary optimization, when you could move this operation to a method...

```
public string GetRegex(string idString)
{
    string[] idlist = new string[] { };
    idlist = idString.Split('-');
    string regex = idlist[0] + "*" + idlist[2] + "*";
    return regex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweak to @Callback Kid's answer:

```
   public string GetRegex(string idString)
   {
      string[] idlist = { };
      idlist = idString.Replace('-', '*').Split('*');
      return string.Concat(idlist[0], idlist[2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner solution to all your code in your question :)

```
new string[] {"ABC1234.PIL.5.0-00028-P-1", "DEF5678.PIL.5.0-00028-E-1", "GHI9101.PIL.4.0-00135-B-1"}.Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, "-.+-(.)-.", "*$1*")).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Though, to better understand it . . .

```
new string[]
{
    "ABC1234.PIL.5.0-00028-P-1", "DEF5678.PIL.5.0-00028-E-1", "GHI9101.PIL.4.0-00135-B-1"
}
.Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, "-.+-(.)-.", "*$1*"))
.ToList()
.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

for just the actual creation of a single entry, you can use this one liner

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("ABC1234.PIL.5.0-00028-P-1", "-.+-(.)-.", "*$1*"))
```